# How can I define an array type in typescript that can connect function and its parameter？

Tags: arrays, typescript, delayed-execution

Here I have three functions and I put them into a literal:

```
type AnyCallback = (...args: any) => unknown;
const callbackAlpha = (data: string) => {
  console.log(data);
  return data.length;
};

const callbackBeta = (data: string, prefix: string) => {
  console.log(data, prefix);
  return prefix + data;
};

const callbackGamma = (data: string, prefix: string, suffix: string) => {
  console.log(data, prefix, suffix);
  return prefix + data + suffix;
};

let allCallBack: Record<string, AnyCallback> = {
  callbackAlpha,
  callbackBeta,
  callbackGamma,
};
```

and then, I want to define an array type to record the function name and parameters when I call it,  the member supposed to be like this:

```
{
   name: //name of a function in the literal
   args: //parameters that needed when I call the function
}
```

Firstly, I tried like this:

```
type TaskType = keyof typeof allCallBack;
type TaskQueue = {
  name: TaskType;
  args: Parameters<(typeof allCallBack)[TaskType]>;
}[];
```

Obviously, it is wrong, because you can give "name" any string value,and "args" can be any parameters of the three functions.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEgZ4m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, when you assign/alias a subtype (a more specific type / narrow type) to a supertype (a less specific type / broader type), the subtype is not preserved in the supertype.

For example,

```js
let a: "foo" = "foo";

let b: string = a;

// typeof b === string and not "foo"
```

The same thing has happened to your functions when you assign subtypes `"callbackAlpha"`, `(data: string) => number` to its corresponding supertypes - `string`, and `(...args: any[]) => any` as defined in `Record<string, AnyCallback>`

If you want TS to preserve the exact type information, then removing the type declaration (`Record`) for `allCallback` would help -

```js
let allCallback = {
  callbackAlpha,
  callbackBeta,
  callbackGamma,
}
```

Here, the type inference works just fine and the exact types are preserved. And then, to construct the `TaskQueue` type preserving the relation/association between the name and args, it can be done using generics -

```js
type TaskType = keyof typeof allCallBack;
type TaskQueueItem<Name extends TaskType> = {
    name: Name,
    args: Parameters<(typeof allCallBack)[Name]>
}
type TaskQueue = TaskQueueItem<TaskType>[];
```

For example,

```js
const myAlphaName = "callbackAlpha" as const;
const myBetaName = "callbackBeta" as const;
const myAlphaTask: TaskQueueItem<typeof myAlphaName> = {
    name: myAlphaName,
    args: ["a"]
};
const myBetaTask: TaskQueueItem<typeof myBetaName> = {
    name: myBetaName,
    args: ["a", "b"]
};
const myAllTasks: TaskQueue = [myAlphaTask, myBetaTask];
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAwgQwDaoEbIMYGsoC8UAFAHTnIBOA5gM4BcUyCAlIQHxQCucucA9gHc4AbgBQ2fnFrAo2NJhy4YqMAAtkhEgBNkwZIxmUAlnGpsCnAN5iocqbX6oIpVP2rFd+luLuUIwFyUcFBeyK4QZsBq4gC+4hIOsvLoWHgAQgGaRJ56BlBGptQANFBg-gBmxgAehsAmZhbWtvbSTi5uHmGl5RBV1T4t-oHBZZU1UADUoXlxCZLSyQppuADiyAC2G9k6eXUNJWN9NftFpbRcFf2njRxQNnYLjs6u7rn6PePV55f9g34BIIhXr9KYzfRgi5XGpzMRiZyyBQodDpJRaB5yZZKFTqZDFFopRQZLL4x5YvDrLZ4sTxOGgSBQAAqyFouEZ4GgRFwEBA-AqUHpED5THQyNQqLw4kFTJZuAAilwIIqAJLACAbAA8ADlNtAINU1XBtLQZaz2ZBOEQMXY4LrGDqNhBSXYmDQGFAAApUXVqyi0DXEQXCpEKCW4FgAbQdEAAuuwaWJpczWQqlZzTfLFSq1Zrk2yOewIzH5kkoBsQDiNNGtAAiQkrSvIGtME1PYDiNtlkCZfTVoh18m4HtNlutGQd0vlxt5xh51PZ9UaoP8qeqKu6y33Fo2u1dxvR512Kh0RgRmtNmM0ieLLvDmcZ+cQVWL5e3rLRzfWqC2x2McvDg9t1dE8oDPJtShrDAa0vWlO1XVA83dOcs3TCNV1xPNSn-LI82LOEgA)

Comment: Your `TaskQueue` type is too permissive, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9QkVN).

Comment: how to achieve the following:
myAllTasks.push({
  name:myAlphaName,
  args:["a","b"]
})       //type check not allowed